# Explanation of notation in $\{P(u), P(X)\in \mathbb C[X]\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

I have the following extract from a question:

[image]

I do not understand what the following are:

- $P$
- $X$
- $\mathbb{C}[X]$

This is from an extra question on a course on Linear Algebra, however, I have never seen this notation before. If someone could clarify this I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\mathbb{C}[X]$ is the set of polynomials in the variable $X$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{C}$. Then $P(X)$ is one of those polynomials. For an endomorphism $u$ it makes sense to talk about $P(u)$.

In words (which would be better than symbols) you are asked to prove that every endomorphism of the form $P(u)$ commutes with $u$.

(I have never seen $\mathbb{C}(u)$ as notation for the set of endomorphisms of that form.)

Comment: To OP: If $P(X) = a_0+a_1X+\cdots+a_nX^n \in \Bbb C[X]$, then $P(u) = a_0\text{id}_E+a_1u+\cdots+a_nu^n \in \mathcal{L}(E)$.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, $P$ stands for polynomial $X$ is the variable of this polynomial, and $\mathbb C [X]$ is the set of all complex polynomials.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{C}[X]$ is a polynomial ring (a set of polynomials with complex coefficients) with $X$ being the variable, which means $P$ is a polynomial with its coefficients in $\mathbb{C}$.